# Can we add a ordinal bigger than every other ordinal and end up with a transitive model?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

Given some (set sized) transitive model of ZFC, $M$ we can construct Hyper-$M$ as follows. We construct an ultrafilter $U$ on $Ord_M$ such that $(\exists \alpha.S = \{ \beta : \beta > \alpha \}) \implies S \in U$. Hyper-$M$ is then $M^{|Ord_M|}/U$ (by analogy with the name Hyperreals).

Note that Hyper-$M$ is an elementary extension of $M$, and moreover is contains an ordinal greater than every ordinal in $M$, namely $H = (0,1,2,\dots,\beta,\dots)/U$. This is because for any ordinal $\alpha = (\alpha, \alpha, \dots, \alpha, \dots)/U$, the set of indices $H_i > \alpha_i$ is equal to $\{ \beta : \beta > \alpha \} \in U$.

My question:

> Is Hyper-$M$ isomorphic to some transitive model of ZFC? If not, how about an elementarily equivalent transitive model?

Comment: Inner model refers to a proper class. How do you *formalize* this ultrapower, since its elements are equivalence classes of *proper* classes? You should read about mice.

Comment: I mean, how do you even formalize a filter on proper classes? And in the scenario, for the ultrapower to be isomorphic to an inner model it would have to be well-founded (because inner models are literally subclasses of the universe) and it would have to have the same ordinals. But it is not hard to check that this will not be the case if the ultrafilter is non-principal. Either the result is ill-founded, or it will have more ordinals (or you only measure *set* functions, which then makes it a whole other question, and not the one you refer to).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm taking $M$ to be set sized. Sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: An inner model is by definition a transitive class containing all ordinals which satisfies ZFC. Do you perhaps mean merely *transitive model*?

Comment: You are saying "Let $A$ be a set sized proper class". I know that you're not familiar with the standard terminology in set theory, which is why I make these remarks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh yes, I meant transitive model. Sorry.

Comment: So what you're really asking is ultimately: "Is the ultrapower of a well-founded model $M$ of ZFC, with $Ord^M$ as its index set, necessarily well-founded?" The answer to that is **no**. If not, what are you asking? (Meanwhile, re: your last sentence, certainly it's elementarily equivalent to $M$ itself ...)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, do transitive models need to have well-founded ordinals? I didn't know that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The [infinite napkin](http://web.evanchen.cc/napkin.html) defines inner model as a transitive model that satisfies ZFC. I think it is wrong, then, right?

Comment: @PyRulez Well, any transitive set at all is $\in$-well-founded ...

Comment: I don't know what that is, and frankly I don't have the time to look into it. If someone defined "inner model" as a transitive model of ZFC, that someone is either not familiar with actual standard usage of the term, or that someone was sloppy.

Comment: And while that napkin thing looks impressive, if you want to converse with set theorists about set theory, it is best to study from sources that are "verified" by set theorists and use the standard terminology in a standard way (I'm giving leeway to things which are not standard, or have several names or meanings).

Comment: The infinite napkin does indeed look impressive, and I commend the author; but I suspect it's more solid on topics within the author's expertise. This is always the danger with single-author very-sweeping texts, and this is a case where there's a small (but non-negligible) issue.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/9010/5442

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: What does the [logic] tag add to the question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila because we're talking about models.

Comment: @PyRulez: Okay... and?

Comment: @AsafKaragila models are studied in logic

Comment: That's like saying that any question involving sets is automatically discrete mathematics or set theory. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off the comments to the question, I think the following is the answer:

First, a quick fact:

- The following are equivalent for a set model $M$ of ZFC:

  - $M$ is isomorphic to a transitive model of ZFC.
  - $M$ is well-founded.
  - $Ord^M$ is well-ordered with respect to $\in^M$.
  - For each $\alpha\in Ord^M$, $\{m\in M: m\in^M\alpha\}$ is well-ordered with respect to $\in^M$.

Clearly $(1)$ implies $(2)$, and from $(2)$ and the Mostowski collapse we get $(1)$. The equivalence between $(3)$ and $(4)$ is because any linear order all of whose proper initial segments are well-ordered is itself a well-order. $(2)$ clearly implies $(3)$, and from $(3)$ and thinking about rank in the cumulative hierarchy we get $(2)$.

With this in mind, you are ultimately asking:

> Suppose we have a well-founded model $M$ of ZFC and $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $Ord^M$ such that every "up-set" is in $\mathcal{U}$. Need $\prod_{Ord^M} M/\mathcal{U}$ be well-founded?

This is ultimately addressed by the notion of **completeness** of an ultrafilter. An ultrafilter $\mathcal{W}$ on a set $I$ is $\kappa$-complete if for every $S\subseteq\mathcal{W}$ with $\vert S\vert<\kappa$ we have $\bigcap S\in\mathcal{W}$, that is, if $\mathcal{W}$ is closed under size-less-than-$\kappa$ intersections. Every ultrafilter is $\omega$-complete, and the first interesting situation occurs when we consider $\omega_1$-completeness (also called countable completeness). Here's the key observation:

- Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is an infinite linear order, $I$ is some index set, and $\mathcal{W}$ is an ultrafilter on $I$ which is not $\omega_1$-closed. Then - even if $\mathcal{L}$ was well-ordered! - $\prod_I\mathcal{L}/\mathcal{U}$ is ill-founded.

Conversely, we have:

- If $\mathcal{L}$ is a well-ordering and $\mathcal{U}$ is an $\omega_1$-closed ultrafilter on an arbitrary index set $I$, then $\prod_I\mathcal{L}/\mathcal{U}$ is well-ordered.

In combination with the "quick fact" above *(hint: take $\mathcal{L}$ to be $Ord^M$)* this tells us:

> If $M$ is a transitive model of ZFC, then $\prod_IM/\mathcal{U}$ is isomorphic to a transitive model of ZFC iff $\mathcal{U}$ is $\omega_1$-closed.

By a standard Zorn's lemma argument, we can cook up non-$\omega_1$-closed appropriate ultrafilters, so the answer to your question is **no**. Indeed, **well-foundedness is hard to preserve**: the existence of an $\omega_1$-complete (nonprincipal) ultrafilter on *any* set is equivalent to the existence of a measurable cardinal, which is a fairly powerful large cardinal axiom (the biggest of the smalls and the smallest of the bigs, really).

Comment: Meanwhile, the answer to your last sentence is trivially yes: any ultrapower is elementarily equivalent to its "root."

Comment: Oh, duh.$\text{}$

Comment: I think it's worth adding that given an $\omega_1$-complete (uniform) ultrafilter, the ultrapower will be isomorphic to a transitive model. So its possible for Hyper-$M$ to be isomorphic to a transitive model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Comment: @StefanMesken Included. (Unless I'm missing something, uniformity isn't necessary.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Uniformity isn't necessary. I just added it to emphasize that there are nontrivial Hyper-$M$ (namely those not isomorphic to $M$) that can be well-founded -- assuming some large cardinals.

Comment: @PyRulez Btw I think proving this equivalence is a reasonable exercise -- it's not entirely trivial but not too challenging either.

Comment: $\prod_I M/\cal U$ is a weird way of writing $M^I/\cal U$.

Answer (score 2):

Noah did an excellent job answering the body of your question. Just for fun I will ignore the body of your question and answer the question in your title instead in a slightly different, but certainly related, way:

> Can we add a[n] ordinal bigger than every other ordinal and end up with a transitive model [via an ultrapower construction]?

The answer is again 'yes'. Under mild assumptions (much weaker than the existence of a measurable cardinal) there is a structure (a so-called mouse) $0^{\#} = (L_\alpha; \in, F)$, where $L_{\alpha}$ is a countable initial segment of the constructible universe and $F$ is a (not $\omega_1$-complete) ultrafilter on some $\kappa$ such that 
$$(L_{\alpha}; \in) \models \mathrm{ZFC}^{-} \text{ and } \kappa \text{ is the largest cardinal}
$$
with the property that $\mathrm{Ult}(L_{\alpha}; F) = (X; E)$ is well-founded. Here

- $X$ consists of all $\sim$-equivalence classes $[f]$ for $f \colon \kappa \to L_{\alpha}$, $f \in L_{\alpha}$ and
  $$
  f \sim g : \iff \{ \xi < \kappa \mid f(\xi) = g(\xi) \} \in F,
  $$
- $E$ is a relation on $X \times X$, intended to interpret $\dot{\in}$, given by
  $$
  [f] E [g] : \iff \{ \xi < \kappa \mid f(\xi) \in g(\xi) \} \in F.
  $$

Since $(X; E)$ is also extensional, it will be isomorphic to some transitive structure $(X; E) \cong (Y; \in)$ and in fact $Y = L_{\beta}$ for some $\beta > \alpha$. In particular $L_{\alpha} \cap \mathrm{Ord} = \alpha < \beta = L_{\beta} \cap \mathrm{Ord}$.

Comment: Note to the OP: in the literature you'll see a couple different definitions of $0^\sharp$. The most common "introductory" one is a certain *set of numbers*, namely the set of (Godel numbers of) formulas which are true of a (certain) set of indiscernibles. The one Stefan's given, however, turns out to be in many ways the more useful one in terms of how it generalizes, and they are in all important senses equivalent. For details, see [this somewhat introductory paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687795). (The "somewhat" is because it is still difficult - but it's the best introduction I know.)