# Is the definability axiom schema consistent with ZF?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let us construct an axiom schema that declares that every set is definable from previous sets. For any formulas $\phi$, $\pi$, $\tau$, the following is instance of this axiom schema:

$$\forall x\forall y.\left(
\begin{array} {rl}
 & \phi(\emptyset) \\ 
\land & \phi(\mathbb N) \\
\land & (\phi(x) \land \phi(y) \implies \phi(\{x,y\}) \\
\land & (\phi(x) \implies \phi (\bigcup x)) \\
\land & (\phi(x) \implies \phi (P(x))) \\
\land & (\phi(x) \implies \phi(\{z \in x: \pi(z)\})) \\
\land & (\text{$\tau$ is a function formula} \land \phi(x) \implies \phi(\tau[x]))\end{array}
\right)
 \implies \forall x. \phi(x)$$

It essentially goes through each of the ZF axioms, constructing a statement saying that $\phi$ satisfies the set is defines. For example, $(\text{$\tau$ is a function} \land \phi(x) \implies \phi(pi[x]))$ represents the axiom schema of replacement. The axiom then states that this statement implies that *all* sets satisfy $\phi$.

Note in particular that this is more restrictive than $V = L$, since it asserts that ordinals need to be definable as well.

In particular, it implies there are no inaccessible cardinals.

Is this axiom schema consistient with ZF? (Also does it have a name?)

EDIT: The motivation for this axiom is to be comparable to the induction scheme on peano arithmetic. Essentially, its asking if we make ZF more like peano arithmetic, is it still consistient? We could even replace this with a second order axiom, and then ask if like peano arithmetic, it becomes categorical! Of course, this would be a different set theory then the normally envisioned one, but it is still of interest.

Comment: Con(ZFC) does not imply there are inaccessible cardinals

Comment: Rather than just posting a problem, you could improve the post by adding more context. What is the motivation for the problem? What question does it address?  What attempts have you made to solve it?  Posts that merely state a problem are generally discouraged, but this might appear to be a pattern; here is a a similarly unmotivated post from just a few minutes ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817100/can-we-add-a-ordinal-bigger-than-every-other-ordinal-and-end-up-with-a-transitiv

Comment: @CarlMummert Okay, I tried to add more motivation.

Comment: There is already an induction schema for ZF, and it is equivalent to Replacement (over ZF-Replacement, of course). Or $\in$-induction, which is equivalent to Regularity (over ZF-Regularity, of course).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but this is a "different" one. It basically says that only definable sets exist (or as close as we can get with first order logic). Foundations   is a induction on membership, not definition.

Comment: I don't see why this implies "only definable sets exist". How do you even define "definable set" internally?

Comment: @PyRulez Another way to make long formulas readable is to break it into $n$ parts, with the first $n-1$ being definitions and the $n^\text{th}$ formula putting the definitions together into the proposition.  But that probably isn't necessary here.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm confused. Wouldn't using the formula $\phi(x) : x\text{ is a cardinal} \implies x\text{ is not inaccessible}$ imply there are no inaccessible cardinals, which is something that ZF can not normally show.

Comment: @PyRulez Did you intend to have some sort of a $\forall \pi$ in the formula to indicate "any instance of the comprehension schema" ?

Comment: @DanielV $\pi$ is a formula, so you can't quantify over it. So no. (Thanks for your edit, btw.)

Comment: @CarlMummert No, because of powerset.

Comment: @PyRulez: perhaps the issue is with the $\phi(y)$ at the end. This is why the motivation is important, because it is not clear at first what formula is really being expressed, A more clear motivation of what the 6th and 7th clauses are supposed to say would be beneficial.

Comment: @CarlMummert In an edit, I said all of the formulas represent an axiom of ZF.

Comment: @PyRulez: I am not sure that last clause truly represents the replacement scheme of ZF - that is the issue that I ran into earlier, no?  The replacement scheme would allow $\pi$ to be a definable class rather than a set.  I am not sure what $\pi$ is in that clause above.

Comment: Whoops, you're only inducting with a single $\pi$ at a time? That throws my entire intuition about what you're trying to do out of whack.

Comment: Instead of "definable" it seems that what you're really after here is, "is the value of a closed term in the language you get from adding Skolem functions for each of the $\forall\exists_!$ axioms". However, for comparison to PA, note that the first-order PA induction axiom _tries its best_ to say that everything is the value of a closed term in the language $\{0,S\}$ -- but is well know to _fail_ to achieve that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Actually, it should be two different formulas. Didn't realize that made a difference.

Comment: You're still inducting over only a single $\pi$ and a single $\tau$ at a time.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah, I'm not sure there's a way around that. I want to keep things first order.

Answer (score 6):

Your proposed axiom schema is not consistent with ZF:

ZF proves that $V_{\omega+\omega}$ exists, and if we instantiate your axiom schema with

- $\phi(x)$ meaning $x\in V_{\omega+\omega}$
- $\pi(x)$ meaning some tautology
- $\tau(x,y)$ meaning $x=y$

then it is easy to establish the premises of your schema. (The two last conjuncts on the LHS become trivial with this $\pi$ and $\tau$). It then concludes $\forall x: x\in V_{\omega+\omega}$, or in other words $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a universal set, which is known to be inconsistent with Selection.

The fact that there are instances with more complex $\pi$ and $\tau$ that are not as obviously inconsistent with ZF doesn't prevent *this* instance from being inconsistent.

---

You might be able to say something closer to what you *intend* if you work in something like NBG instead of ZF, so you can quantify directly over your $\pi$ and $\tau$.